# How to use "TRUNCATE TABLE" MySQL statement?

Tags: database, mysql

I have tried dbDelta and $wpdb->query, they does not work. Does anyone has any ideas?

Comment: What is the error? You can dump it with the following call right after you executed the statement: $e = $wpdb->query($sql); die(var_dump($e));

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As try today, truncate is WAY BETTER that DELETE, because DELETE broke the site, and trucate just empty the table, here is the working code :

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->query('TRUNCATE TABLE wp_posts');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this forum entry](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?636176-Wordpress-Plugins-Does-TRUNCATE-work-with-wpdb), truncate does not work.  I would guess that since it's such a destructive query, that it's filtered by the class.  There is also [this Trac Post](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11372), which if I am reading it right, disallows DDL statements.

Comment: Well, maybe I use DELETE instead of truncate.

Comment: @goodseller Not sure what you're trying to do, so it might not be important to you--but note that DELETE does not reset any auto-incrementing columns. So even though your table will be empty, the next item ID will pick up where the last auto- incremented value left off.

Comment: @MathSmath Yeah~ That's true, so true. However is there any way to do so?

Comment: I found it: $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT=0") Thanks @MathSmath :)

Comment: 1. linked forum entry code did not work because of a typo. 2. trac ticket just talks about return values from ddl statements.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are similar answers above but in the above answers, the table wp_post used if by mistake someone uses that code will lose his all posts.

> So sharing a correct way to truncate.

```
   global $wpdb;
   $table_name = $wpdb->base_prefix.'name_of_table_without_prefix';
   $wpdb->query("TRUNCATE TABLE $table_name");
```